# Downloadable sources for com.eviware.soapui packages?

Tags: java, package, soapui

I'm looking for downloadable sources for com.eviware.soapui packages as well as some child packages. SOAP UI seems to be an open source tool, so I'm hopeful that this thing is available. Any help, please?

Comment: I don't see how this is a question that might invite opinionated answers. I'm not looking for recommendations or favorites, I'm looking for a location where I can find the source for a very specific package. The problem is that a java framework I am to work with uses this package, and the solution I'm looking for is the location of the source so I can learn how things work in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sources for SoapUI are hosted by GitHub and can be found at https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/.
Here you can also have a peek of what is coming in the next release by looking at the branch called *next*. To download the sources without having to fiddle with git you can press the *Download ZIP* button to the right.

The sources are also included in the installation packages of the the free version of SoapUI, which can be found at http://www.soapui.org/.